# I feel like an idiot, why can't I make a servo move with the boilerplate code?

Tags: arduino-nano, servo, arduino-micro

So I was working on a far more grand project, until I discovered that I couldn't get any of my servos to move.

I've gone back to basics, and am trying to just get the [boilerplate code found here, working](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sweep).

```c++
#include <Servo.h>

Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo
// twelve servo objects can be created on most boards

int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object
}

void loop() {
  for (pos = 0; pos <= 180; pos += 1) { // goes from 0 degrees to 180 degrees
    // in steps of 1 degree
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
  for (pos = 180; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) { // goes from 180 degrees to 0 degrees
    myservo.write(pos);              // tell servo to go to position in variable 'pos'
    delay(15);                       // waits 15ms for the servo to reach the position
  }
}
```

[Here are pictures of my setup.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK6ij.jpg)

Comment: You can embed pictures into your question (I'm not sure of the limit if you don't have much rep - at least one or two). For short code it helps to embed the code as well - I did that for you. You can provide a link so people know where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see that could be the problem is with your servo wiring. It seems that most servos use this kind of wiring [image: Servo Wires]
 Which is the way that you seem to wire it, but depending on how Radioshack servos are made the signal wire could correspond with a different wire. I imagine this could possibly be on the packaging so I would start by looking there to confirm your wiring.